# resetting liquid slider height based on bootstrap datatable height

Tags: javascript

I have several bootstrap datatables embedded in a liquid slider. Whenever i search for something inside a datatable, the datatables size changes. However the liquid slider doesn't notice that and won't update its own size. So i wrote this function to listen to all search events and reset the liquid sliders size whenever a search event happens:

```
var sliderCallback = $.data($('#slider-1')[0], 'liquidSlider');
if (sliderCallback != undefined && dataTables.size() > 0) {
    dataTables.on("search.dt", function (e) {
        sliderCallback.adjustHeight(false, $("#" + e.target.id).height());
    }).DataTable();
}
```

This will reset the liquid sliders size whenever a search event occurs, however the `$("#" + e.target.id).height` gives me a lot of stupid values back, that don't make any sense.

Sometimes the slider will make itself so small, the datatable will not be visible, etc.

What i tried:
- $("#" + e.target.id).height()
- $("#" + e.target.id)[0].clientHeight

and some other iterations of that

It still gives me only stupid values back... Any ideas on how to get the real height of the  elem so i can properly update the slider height?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same problem:

The problem was the "search.dt" event firing before the resizing happened. Therefore it returned wrong height calculations because it computed them before it actually made sense.

Simply swapping to "draw.dt" made the deal.